# Mock cubit that is required in bloc, mocktail

Tags: flutter, mocking

In my project I have a Bloc that required Cubit. I am trying to test that case by `testWidget`. There are complete files to reproduce what I have, I hope you easily run my case.

#### lib/add_item/bloc/add_item_bloc.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/cubit/view_item_cubit.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/view_item.dart';

part 'add_item_event.dart';
part 'add_item_state.dart';

class AddItemBloc extends Bloc<AddItemEvent, AddItemState> {
  AddItemBloc({
    required ViewItemCubit viewItemCubit,
  })  : _viewItemCubit = viewItemCubit,
        super(const AddItemState()) {
    on<TestEvent>(_onTestEvent);
  }

  final ViewItemCubit _viewItemCubit;

  Future<void> _onTestEvent(
    TestEvent event,
    Emitter<AddItemState> emit,
  ) async {
    await _viewItemCubit.fetchViewItems(event.value);
    final viewItem = _viewItemCubit.state.viewItems;
    emit(
      state.copyWith(
        filteredItems: viewItem,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

#### lib/add_item/bloc/add_item_event.dart

```
part of 'add_item_bloc.dart';

abstract class AddItemEvent extends Equatable {
  const AddItemEvent();
}

class TestEvent extends AddItemEvent {
  const TestEvent({required this.value});

  final String value;
  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [value];
}
```

#### lib/add_item/bloc/add_item_state.dart

```
part of 'add_item_bloc.dart';

class AddItemState extends Equatable {
  const AddItemState({
    this.filteredItems = const [],
    this.message = '',
  });

  final List<ViewItem> filteredItems;
  final String message;

  AddItemState copyWith({
    List<ViewItem>? filteredItems,
    String? message,
  }) {
    return AddItemState(
      filteredItems: filteredItems ?? this.filteredItems,
      message: message ?? this.message,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        filteredItems,
        message,
      ];
}
```

#### lib/view_item/view_item.dart

```
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part './view_item.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class ViewItem extends Equatable {
  const ViewItem({
    required this.itemId,
    required this.documentId,
    required this.materialId,
    required this.totalQuantity,
    required this.materialDescription,
    required this.materialNumber,
    required this.documentNumber,
    required this.assignedQuantity,
    required this.wbsId,
    required this.label,
  });

  factory ViewItem.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$ViewItemFromJson(json);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$ViewItemToJson(this);

  static const ViewItem empty = ViewItem(
    itemId: 0,
    documentId: 0,
    materialId: 0,
    totalQuantity: 0,
    materialDescription: '',
    materialNumber: '',
    documentNumber: 0,
    assignedQuantity: 0,
    wbsId: 0,
    label: '',
  );

  final int itemId;
  final int documentId;
  final int materialId;
  final double totalQuantity;
  final String materialDescription;
  final String materialNumber;
  final int documentNumber;
  final double assignedQuantity;
  final int? wbsId;
  final String label;

  ViewItem copyWith({
    int? item2locationId,
    int? itemId,
    int? documentId,
    int? materialId,
    double? totalQuantity,
    String? materialDescription,
    String? materialNumber,
    int? documentNumber,
    double? assignedQuantity,
    int? wbsId,
    String? label,
  }) {
    return ViewItem(
      itemId: itemId ?? this.itemId,
      documentId: documentId ?? this.documentId,
      materialId: materialId ?? this.materialId,
      totalQuantity: totalQuantity ?? this.totalQuantity,
      materialNumber: materialNumber ?? this.materialNumber,
      documentNumber: documentNumber ?? this.documentNumber,
      assignedQuantity: assignedQuantity ?? this.assignedQuantity,
      materialDescription: materialDescription ?? this.materialDescription,
      wbsId: wbsId ?? this.wbsId,
      label: label ?? this.label,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        itemId,
        documentId,
        materialId,
        totalQuantity,
        materialDescription,
        materialNumber,
        documentNumber,
        assignedQuantity,
        wbsId,
        label,
      ];
}
```

#### lib/view_item/view_item.g.dart

```
// GENERATED CODE - DO NOT MODIFY BY HAND

part of './view_item.dart';

// **************************************************************************
// JsonSerializableGenerator
// **************************************************************************

ViewItem _$ViewItemFromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => $checkedCreate(
      'ViewItem',
      json,
      ($checkedConvert) {
        final val = ViewItem(
          itemId: $checkedConvert('item_id', (v) => v as int),
          documentId: $checkedConvert('document_id', (v) => v as int),
          materialId: $checkedConvert('material_id', (v) => v as int),
          totalQuantity:
              $checkedConvert('total_quantity', (v) => (v as num).toDouble()),
          materialDescription:
              $checkedConvert('material_description', (v) => v as String),
          materialNumber:
              $checkedConvert('material_number', (v) => v as String),
          documentNumber: $checkedConvert('document_number', (v) => v as int),
          assignedQuantity: $checkedConvert(
              'assigned_quantity', (v) => (v as num).toDouble()),
          wbsId: $checkedConvert('wbs_id', (v) => v as int?),
          label: $checkedConvert('label', (v) => v as String),
        );
        return val;
      },
      fieldKeyMap: const {
        'itemId': 'item_id',
        'documentId': 'document_id',
        'materialId': 'material_id',
        'totalQuantity': 'total_quantity',
        'materialDescription': 'material_description',
        'materialNumber': 'material_number',
        'documentNumber': 'document_number',
        'assignedQuantity': 'assigned_quantity',
        'wbsId': 'wbs_id'
      },
    );

Map<String, dynamic> _$ViewItemToJson(ViewItem instance) => <String, dynamic>{
      'item_id': instance.itemId,
      'document_id': instance.documentId,
      'material_id': instance.materialId,
      'total_quantity': instance.totalQuantity,
      'material_description': instance.materialDescription,
      'material_number': instance.materialNumber,
      'document_number': instance.documentNumber,
      'assigned_quantity': instance.assignedQuantity,
      'wbs_id': instance.wbsId,
      'label': instance.label,
    };
```

#### lib/view_item/cubit/view_item_cubit.dart

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/view_item.dart';

part 'view_item_state.dart';

class ViewItemCubit extends Cubit<ViewItemState> {
  ViewItemCubit() : super(const ViewItemState());

  Future<void> fetchViewItems(String documentNumber) async {
    emit(state.copyWith(status: ViewItemStatus.loading));

    try {
      final viewItem1 = ViewItem.empty.copyWith(label: 'test_1');
      final viewItem2 = ViewItem.empty.copyWith(label: 'test_2');
      final viewItem3 = ViewItem.empty.copyWith(label: 'test_3');
      emit(state.copyWith(
        status: ViewItemStatus.success,
        viewItems: [viewItem1, viewItem2, viewItem3],
      ));
    } catch (_) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: ViewItemStatus.timeout, message: 'error'));
    }
  }
}
```

#### lib/view_item/cubit/view_item_state.dart

```
part of 'view_item_cubit.dart';

enum ViewItemStatus { initial, loading, success, failure, timeout }

extension ViewItemStatusX on ViewItemStatus {
  bool get isInitial => this == ViewItemStatus.initial;
  bool get isLoading => this == ViewItemStatus.loading;
  bool get isSuccess => this == ViewItemStatus.success;
  bool get isFailure => this == ViewItemStatus.failure;
  bool get isTimeout => this == ViewItemStatus.timeout;
}

@JsonSerializable()
class ViewItemState extends Equatable {
  final ViewItemStatus status;
  final List<ViewItem> viewItems;
  final String? message;

  const ViewItemState({
    this.status = ViewItemStatus.initial,
    this.viewItems = const [],
    this.message,
  });

  ViewItemState copyWith({
    ViewItemStatus? status,
    List<ViewItem>? viewItems,
    String? message,
  }) {
    return ViewItemState(
      message: message ?? this.message,
      status: status ?? this.status,
      viewItems: viewItems ?? this.viewItems,
    );
  }

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [status, viewItems, message];
}
```

#### lib/app.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/add_item/bloc/add_item_bloc.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/cubit/view_item_cubit.dart';

import 'assignment_item_page.dart';

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  const App({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider<ViewItemCubit>(
          create: (context) => ViewItemCubit(),
        ),
        BlocProvider<AddItemBloc>(
          create: (context) => AddItemBloc(
            viewItemCubit: context.read<ViewItemCubit>(),
          ),
        ),
      ],
      child: const AssignmentItemPage(),
    );
  }
}
```

#### lib/assignment_item_page.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/add_item/bloc/add_item_bloc.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/cubit/view_item_cubit.dart';

class AssignmentItemPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const AssignmentItemPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AssignmentItemPage> createState() => _AssignmentItemPageState();
}

class _AssignmentItemPageState extends State<AssignmentItemPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<ViewItemCubit, ViewItemState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return BlocBuilder<AddItemBloc, AddItemState>(
          builder: (context, state) {
            context.read<AddItemBloc>().add(const TestEvent(value: '1234'));
            return const MaterialApp(
              home: Scaffold(
                body: Text('test app'),
              ),
            );
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

#### lib/main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/app.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: kIsWeb
        ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
        : await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
  runApp(const App());
}
```

#### test/widget_test.dart

```
import 'package:bloc_test/bloc_test.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bloc/flutter_bloc.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mocktail/mocktail.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/add_item/bloc/add_item_bloc.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/assignment_item_page.dart';

import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/cubit/view_item_cubit.dart';
import 'package:poc_test_bloc/view_item/view_item.dart';

class MockViewItemCubit extends MockCubit<ViewItemState>
    implements ViewItemCubit {}

void main() {
  group('test test', () {
    late MockViewItemCubit mockViewItemCubit;

    setUp(() {
      mockViewItemCubit = MockViewItemCubit();
    });

    testWidgets('test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
      const viewItem1 = ViewItem(
        itemId: 1,
        documentId: 1,
        materialId: 1,
        totalQuantity: 1,
        materialDescription: 'test',
        materialNumber: '1234567890',
        documentNumber: 1234567890,
        assignedQuantity: 2,
        wbsId: 1,
        label: '1',
      );
      const viewItem2 = ViewItem(
        itemId: 2,
        documentId: 2,
        materialId: 2,
        totalQuantity: 2,
        materialDescription: 'test',
        materialNumber: '1234567891',
        documentNumber: 1234567892,
        assignedQuantity: 3,
        wbsId: 2,
        label: '2',
      );
      when(() => mockViewItemCubit.state).thenReturn(const ViewItemState(
        status: ViewItemStatus.initial,
      ));
      when(() => mockViewItemCubit.fetchViewItems('1234567890'))
          .thenAnswer((_) async {
        const ViewItemState(
          status: ViewItemStatus.success,
          viewItems: [viewItem1, viewItem2],
        );
      });

      await tester.pumpWidget(
        BlocProvider<ViewItemCubit>.value(
          value: mockViewItemCubit,
          child: BlocProvider<AddItemBloc>.value(
            value: AddItemBloc(
              viewItemCubit: mockViewItemCubit,
            ),
            child: const MaterialApp(
              home: AssignmentItemPage(),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
    });
  });
}
```

#### pubspec.yaml

```
name: poc_test_bloc
description: A new Flutter project.
# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `flutter pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number is used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
# In Windows, build-name is used as the major, minor, and patch parts
# of the product and file versions while build-number is used as the build suffix.
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=2.19.2 <3.0.0'

# Dependencies specify other packages that your package needs in order to work.
# To automatically upgrade your package dependencies to the latest versions
# consider running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Alternatively,
# dependencies can be manually updated by changing the version numbers below to
# the latest version available on pub.dev. To see which dependencies have newer
# versions available, run `flutter pub outdated`.
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  equatable: ^2.0.3
  flutter_bloc: ^8.0.1
  json_annotation: ^4.6.0
  hydrated_bloc: ^9.1.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.8

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  bloc_test: ^9.1.0
  json_serializable: ^6.0.0
  mocktail: ^0.3.0

  # The "flutter_lints" package below contains a set of recommended lints to
  # encourage good coding practices. The lint set provided by the package is
  # activated in the `analysis_options.yaml` file located at the root of your
  # package. See that file for information about deactivating specific lint
  # rules and activating additional ones.
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter packages.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Paste the output of running `flutter doctor -v` here.

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.7.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728], locale pl-PL)
    • Flutter version 3.7.3 on channel stable at C:\Program Files\flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git                                 
    • Framework revision 9944297138 (8 weeks ago), 2023-02-08 15:46:04 -0800                     
    • Engine revision 248290d6d5
    • Dart version 2.19.2
    • DevTools version 2.20.1
                                                                                                 
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)                       

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0-rc4)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\plradmkw\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 33.0.0-rc4
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.11\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment Microsoft-22268 (build 11.0.11+9)
    ! Some Android licenses not accepted. To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[√] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

[!] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.5.3)
    • Visual Studio at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community
    • Visual Studio Community 2022 version 17.5.33516.290
    • Windows 10 SDK version 10.0.22000.0
    X Visual Studio is missing necessary components. Please re-run the Visual Studio installer for the "Desktop development with C++" workload, and include these components:
        MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools
         - If there are multiple build tool versions available, install the latest
        C++ CMake tools for Windows
        Windows 10 SDK

[!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    • Try updating or re-installing Android Studio.

[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2022.1)
    • IntelliJ at C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.1
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[√] VS Code (version 1.77.0)
    • VS Code at C:\Users\plradmkw\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.60.0

[√] Connected device (4 available)
    • sdk gphone64 x86 64 (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x64    • Android 13 (API 33) (emulator)
    • Windows (desktop)            • windows       • windows-x64    • Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2728]
    • Chrome (web)                 • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 111.0.5563.65
    • Edge (web)                   • edge          • web-javascript • Microsoft Edge 111.0.1661.54

[√] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

**Expected behavior**
What I expect? I want to receive `viewItems = [viewItem1, viewItem2]` in `AddItemBloc` by `final viewItem = _viewItemCubit.state.viewItems;` that I stubbing it (viewItems) in method:

```
when(() => mockViewItemCubit.fetchViewItems(any())).thenAnswer((_) async {
  const ViewItemState(
    status: ViewItemStatus.success,
      viewItems: [viewItem1, viewItem2],
  );
});
```

but `_viewItemCubit.state.viewItems;` is always empty. I want to use "real" implementation of `AddItemBloc` with mock `ViewItemCubit`. How can I mock it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fetchViewItems` doesn't actually return anything so you can't stub it by returning a value, instead try to stub the Cubit's `state` when `fetchViewItems` is called.

should look something like this:

```
when(() => mockViewItemCubit.fetchViewItems('1234567890'))
    .thenAnswer((_) async {
  when(() => mockViewItemCubit.state).thenReturn(const ViewItemState(
    status: ViewItemStatus.success,
    viewItems: [viewItem1, viewItem2],
  ));
  return;
});
```

Other options include making a Fake implementation of the Cubit.